# Is knowing the Sum and Product of k different natural numbers enough to find them?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, products

Can we uniquely identify the set of *k* different natural numbers (no two are the same) by knowing only their sum and product (and the value of *k* itself)?

Comment: I suggest you try examples, with k equal to 3.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I don't see an obvious 3-number counter-example if $0$ is not a natural number.

Comment: @user21820 Agreed.  Though there are 3-number counterexamples, they take a while to find by hand.

Comment: It's possible for $k=2$. Not for $k \ge 3$.

Comment: Think about polynomials and their coefficients... This would imply that you could find all the roots of a polynomial by simply looking at the first and last coefficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

{4,9,10} and {5,6,12} have the same sum (23) and product (360) so the answer is no.

As such then {4k,9k,10k} and {5k,6k,12k} also have the same sum and product so there is a multitude of counter examples. I'm imagine there are others based on different triples as well.

Comment: First (I think) triple example is: 
$$6\times8\times25=1200\text{ and }6+8+25=39$$
$$5\times10\times24=1200\text{ and }5+10+24=39$$
$$4\times15\times20=1200\text{ and }4+15+20=39$$

Answer (score 5):

I think the minimal counterexample (in the sense of minimal sum) are the triples $\{2,8,9\}$ and $\{ 3,4,12 \}$ for which we have
$$ 2+8+9 = 19 \qquad 2\cdot 8\cdot 9 = 144$$
and 
$$ 3 + 4 + 12 = 19 \qquad 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 12 = 144.$$

Comment: Also, the minimal counterexample in the sense of minimal product is {1, 9, 10} and {2, 3, 15}.